# Ant build file to generate JAR for selenium test cases and run it

Tags: ant, jar, junit, automation, selenium-rc

I have a automation testing project in selenium using Junit framework. Right now I am using ant build file to compile the project and run it and generating the reports.

The project has testsuits that  I am executing from ant build file, namely:
TestSuite1
TestSuite2
TestSuite3
and so on..

But, what I want is to convert this project in a JAR file and run the testsuites in JAR file one by one.

The purpose is that I can create a JAR file of the project and give the JAR file to client so that need for compilation of the project is no longer needed and the client executes the testsuites from JAR file directly having only the JRE on the system and no JDK is required at client side.

I need to know that how to make two build files:

1) That builds the project and convert it into a JAR. This will be used by me to build JAr files.

2) A build file to be given to client that would only execute the JAR file and collect the report.

I am using JUnit framework.

Disclaimer: I am new to ant... :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is not related to selenium, but building of a project.

1) Ant is kind of out of date today, you should check out Maven (especially if you are new to ant). It is newer, more robust integration and building tool. You will be able to easily generate jar file with it. You will be also interested in [selenium maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/) which will start Selenium server for you.

2) I suppose your test suites are JUnit tests. To be able to run it from jar with JRE you need to create "public static void main(String[] args)" method in some class to make it runnable. You will run your Selenium client instances from here. You will also need to start Selenium server from here, which should be also packaged to your jar as library.